# downloadFile with "save as"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, save-as, webclient

I need to write a process to download an html file locally in my vb.net web app. I am currently using `webClient.DownloadFile` :

```
Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/primer.html", _
                        "C:\test.html")
```

Is there a built-in way to do this with a "save as" window instead, so that the user can select the location they would like the file to be saved to? Or would I need to write my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=testfile_file.html");
Response.Write or Response.WriteFile
```

Comment: This is true but be aware different browsers use different encodings for non ascii chars or space

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I realise this isn't an answer to your question (see comment on Thomas' answer), sometimes keeping it simple is a good way to go

```
Please right-click this link and save the file
<a href=""http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/primer.html">HTML Primer</a>
```

Comment: It was merely for an example. here we can use html or jpeg. It can be anything. Isn't that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
Response.ContentType = "report/rpt";

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=CrystalReport1.rpt");

Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt"));

Response.End();
```

Comment: Don't see how this helps in any way that hasn't already been provided. Crystal reports aren't mentioned anywhere...

Comment: It was merely for an example. here we can use html or jpeg. It can be anything. Isn't that ?

Comment: +1 as this is a valid answer. You can use TransmitFile to provide the provide the file trough SaveAs with this code.