# How to display save as file browser when saving a file using asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, file

I am trying to save a file to client side using asp.net mvc (vb).
I can save a file to client side using the following code.

```
Dim Options As New ExportOptions
Dim FileOption As New DiskFileDestinationOptions
Options.ExportDestinationOptions = FileOption
Options.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
Options.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
rptH.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "C:\asd.pdf")
```

Here I am set a destination to save the file. Its working. How a client can choose a destination to save the file? Like the following picture?

[image]

How can I do that??

****** EDIT ********

Iam generating content of the file according to users search criteria and from database.

Comment: _"I can save a file to client side using the following code"_ - no, that's not how the web works, that's not at all how the web works. It seems to work because your (development) server and client (browser) run on the same machine. I picked the entirely wrong duplicate, but see [downloadFile with “save as”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990377/downloadfile-with-save-as) for the proper answer.

Comment: You are write. Iam running the code in local machine. The given link was already tried, but not worked